# Click in button with soapui and selenium

Tags: selenium, grails, soapui

I´m trying to click in a button with soapui & selenium with the following sentence:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait 
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities 
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Window 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException 
import java.util.Date; 
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher


// Create a new instance of the Chrome driver //Set up the driver def
chromeExecLoc = context.expand( '${#Project#chromeExecLoc}' )
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromeExecLoc)

//Define driver WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

def defaultURL = context.expand( '${#Project#urllogin}' ) //def
logoffURL = context.expand( '${#TestSuite#logoffURL}' )


// *******************************************************login*******************************************************

log.info("****** Login ******")


//url driver.get(defaultURL) driver.manage().window().maximize()
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

//load , waiting for login button def loginId = context.expand('${#TestSuite#loginId}' )
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.class(ymwc-trigger)))
```

Properties:

```
<li id="menu-item-31998" class="mymwc-trigger menu-item menu-item-type-custom 
menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31998">
```

I want to click and after that it show a login and pass form but i´ve get an error at the following line of code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.class(ymwc-trigger)))
```

Could you help me? 
thanks

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: groovy.lan.MissingPropertyException: No such property: menu for class

Comment: shouldn't all of your code be in a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `By.class(ymwc-trigger)` you can use the following line of code :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='mymwc-trigger menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom' and starts-with(@class,'menu-item-') and starts-with(@id,'menu-item-')]")))
```

---

### Update

As per your comment as you were seeing the following error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //li[@class='mymwc-trigger menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom' and starts-with(@class,'menu-item-') and starts-with(@id,'menu-item-')] Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32' System info: host: 'ProBook-450-G3', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-103-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_144' Driver info: driver.version: unknown error at line: 49
```

### Reason

The reason is your `Selenium` version: **'2.41.0'** is ancient. `Driver info`: **driver.version: unknown**.

### Solution

Update **`Selenium Client`** to **3.8.1** levels and **`WebDriver`** variant to recent version. Execute your `Test`.

Comment: I am not sure about the `groovy` syntax but the `xpath` is correct. Can you update the question with the error stack trace please?

Comment: thanks! org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //li[@class='mymwc-trigger menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom' and starts-with(@class,'menu-item-') and starts-with(@id,'menu-item-')] Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32' System info: host: 'ProBook-450-G3', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-103-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_144' Driver info: driver.version: unknown error at line: 49

Comment: See, your `Selenium` version: **'2.41.0'** is ancient. Driver info: **driver.version: unknown**. Update both of them to recent levels and retest.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB! now it doesn´t show an error, i´ll try to continue!